# How to get WITH ROLLUP after a sorted limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query to get the number of wins for a football team:

```
SELECT
    IF(grouping(team) IS TRUE, 'All', team) AS team,
    sum(wins)                               AS num_wins
FROM test.seasons
GROUP BY team WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY num_wins;
```

And the result is something like:

```
team  num_wins
All     2552
NE      125
PIT     102
GB      102
SEA     100
...
```

Is there a way to do a `WITH ROLLUP` after a limit? For example, how could I just get the following value on a `LIMIT 2` (limit ignoring the rollup)?

```
team   num_wins
All     227
NE      125
PIT     102
```

If I do a 'normal limit' it includes the `WITH ROLLUP` which is evaluated before the order/limit:

```
SELECT
    IF(grouping(team) IS TRUE, 'All', team) AS team,
    sum(wins)                               AS num_wins
FROM test.seasons
GROUP BY team WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY num_wins DESC limit 2;
```

```
# team, num_wins
All 2552
NE  125
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - but equally, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry see updated question.

Comment: @Strawberry in that case, the `WITH ROLLUP` would have no use at all and I'd do just as well do a `group by limit 2`, right?

Comment: Yep, GROUP BY... ORDER BY...LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN grouping(team) THEN 'All' ELSE team END) AS team,
       SUM(wins)  AS num_wins
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM test.seasons s
      ORDER BY num_wins DESC
      LIMIT 2
     ) s
GROUP BY team WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY num_wins;
```

Comment: I see, I came up with almost the same, using with: `with top2 as (
 SELECT team, sum(wins) cnt from seasons group by team order by cnt desc limit 2
) select * from top2 group by team with rollup` -- is there any difference using a subselect and the with? or do both basically do the same thing?

Comment: @David542 . . . They do basically the same thing.

Comment: I see. So would it not be possible doing the above without a subquery one way or another?

Comment: @David542 . . . You could use a `where` clause, but that would still require a subquery.